# How to link images pr file in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I failed to show the image,
**below the code,**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

img= image.load_img("cnn_happy_notHappy/traing/happy/1.png")
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-2c0e7bdac5f8> in <module>()
----> 1 img= image.load_img("cnn_happy_notHappy/traing/happy/1.png")

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    111         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
--> 113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    114         img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115         if color_mode == 'grayscale':

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cnn_happy_notHappy/traing/happy/1.png'
```

**The folder screenshots where image folder and file have,**
[image: Folder directory]

**Please help me to solve this issue,**

Comment: Mount the google drive first, then load data from it. [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import your images first in google colab then assign it to your img variable.

```
# you can run this in first cell
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
# you can run this is the second cell will show a button to upload the file in google collab
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
# use this after image in uploaded in the previous cell successfullt
img= image.load_img("1.png")
```